# Android 4.4: WebView exposes internal issue HWUI Protection: wrong calling from app context

Tags: android, video

I have an internal issue when trying to play a video, as follows:

11-30 19:42:01.415: E/libGLESv2(31031): HWUI Protection: wrong calling from app context F:ES3-glDeleteTextures.

Any known fix or workaround?

This arises with a Webm media player as follows:

```
<video id="videoReglageVideo"
    width="640" 
    height="360" 
    frameborder="0"
    allowfullscreen
    poster="rsc/videos/RegladeDuSemoirVideo.poster.jpg"
    controls>
    <source ng-if="device.isiOS" src="rsc/videos/ReglageDuSemoir.m4v"  type="video/mp4">
    <source ng-if="!device.isiOS" src="rsc/videos/ReglageDuSemoir.webm"  type="video/webm">
    La vidéo de réglage de semoir n'est pas disponible.
</video>
```

Comment: Did you try on other devices/android os?

Comment: I think it's not possible to stream from android_assets… anyone to confirm? @david

Comment: it would work if the video is stored in the raw folder if the application :http://stackoverflow.com/q/17020270/230825

Comment: It looks this won't work too on android 4.x : https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=387898

Comment: Any luck on this issue ?